# Como llamar a una funcion desde Sweetalert

Tags: mysql, funciones, sweetalert2

Tengo el siguiente codigo que se llama una vez que se hace clic en un botón.

```js
if ($('#forma_pago_1')[0].checked===true){
    if( fecha_rb1 === '' && suma_pagos === pago_total ){
        Swal.fire({ 
            icon: 'error',
            title: 'No ha señalado la Fecha de Pago',
            text: 'Favor de ingresar una fecha en el apartado de Referencia Bancaria',
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            confirmButtonText: 'ACEPTAR'                             
        }); // final del swal //
    } else if(fecha_rb1 !== '' &&  suma_pagos === pago_total){
               Swal.fire({ 
                    icon: 'success',
                    html: '<b>Monto a pagar...</b>'+
                          '<br>$'+ suma_pagos +'.00'+
                          '<br><b>Fecha de pago</b>' +
                          '<br>Fecha Pago 1: '+ fecha_rb1 +' ',
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                    confirmButtonText: 'ACEPTAR',   
                    cancelButtonText: 'CANCELAR'  
               }) // final del swal // 
               .

then((result) => {
                    if (result.value) {
                    document.getElementById('RegistrarPago').disabled = false;
            }
      })// fin del then
    } //fin del else if                    
  } // fin de pago con referencia bancaria
```

En este momento al darle clic en el boton ACEPTAR me permite habilitar un boton con la linea :

```
then((result) => {
                if (result.value) {
                document.getElementById('RegistrarPago').disabled = false;
        }
```

el boton que se habilita, me permite llamar a una funcion que guarda un registro en la base de datos de mysql, para llegar a esto me tomo varios horas, haciendo pruebas, leyendo aqui en este foro y la documentacion de sweetalert y otras paginas, hasta que logre que me funcionara esto.

Pero ahora me piden que en lugar que habilite el boton, que al momento que haga clic en el boton "ACEPTAR" del sweetalert, en ese momento genere la solicitud de guardar la informacion en la base de datos.  Ya estuve revisando la documentacion pero de verdad no entiendo como hacer la peticion desde el sweetalert hacia una funcion.

Mi funcion para guardar los registros se llama : `function registra_pagos(obj){}` se encuentra en el mismo cuerpo del script , uso ajax para pasar los datos y guardar en la base de datos en mysql
alguien que me pueda dar un norte.

Se agradece de antemano su atencion.

Saludos

Comment: Lo que tienes dentro del `then()`, el `document.getElement()` que hace eso?

Comment: @Luis es el nombre de un boton = <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="RegistrarPago" name="RegistrarPago" disabled="" Onclick="registra_pagos(this)"> Registrar Pago </button>  cuando termina de procesar la ventana y le das ACEPTAR cierra la ventana, y habilita el boton, este boton mandar llamar a una funcion que envia los datos via Ajax a la BD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hasta donde entiendo, es que quieres saber cómo, al momento de darle "ACEPTAR" al botón que te muestra el Sweetalert te permita hacer una llamada ajax a un endpoint y ejecutar lo que necesitas en la base de datos, ¿cierto?

Básicamente, la respuesta de la promesa de Sweetalert cuando le das aceptar te va a devolver un objeto y en este tendrás la propiedad `isConfirmed` que se setea a `true` cuando el usuario le da en el botón "ACEPTAR". Entonces, cuando ese valor sea true haces tu llamado ajax a tu endpoint o llamas a la función `registra_pagos(obj)`

Igualmente te dejo un snippet de muestra. Saludos

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
const img = document.querySelector('img');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  Swal.fire({
    title: 'Está por ejecutar un pago',
    icon: 'success',
    html: '<b>Monto a pagar...</b>'+
          '<br>$2000.00'+
          '<br><b>Fecha de pago</b>' +
          '<br>Fecha Pago 1: 12/04/2023 ',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: 'ACEPTAR',   
    cancelButtonText: 'CANCELAR'  
  })
  .then(res => {
    if(res.isConfirmed) {
    // en tu caso sería llamar a function registra_pagos(obj){}
      fetch('https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search?limit=1')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
          img.src = res[0].url
        })
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>

<button>Ejecutar pago</button>

<img src="" alt="gatitos">
```

Comment: La llamada a la función requiere alguna sintaxis ?

Comment: ¿Cómo así que si la función requiere alguna sintaxis? ¿Cuál función?

Comment: Si veo que utilizas fetch('https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search?limit=1') para que se cargen la imagenes de los gatitos,  pero dentro del sweetalert no tengo ni idea de como escribir la linea para que llame a la funcion que necesito, ya lo intente de varias formas y no hace nada,  y no encuentro nada relacionado, a lo mejor ya es cegera de laboratorio.  Saludos

Comment: te puse el caso del fetch porque con eso puedes hacer tu petición AJAX a dónde necesitas porque además decías que así lo hacías. Ahora, como te dejé en el comentario, también puedes llamar a tu función que lo hace, pero no sé qué hace o qué parámetros le pasas a dicha función

Comment: Esta ventana es el resultado de una validacion,  si cumple le das aceptar, habilita otro boton, al hacer click en este manda llamar una funcion que recopila los datos validados y los envio via ajax a un archivo php donde se lleva a cabo la insercion a la base de datos.  La idea de quien me cordina, es evitar ese segundo boton y que desde que haces click en el boton ACEPTAR del swettalert se enviaran los datos a la base.

Comment: Bueno, es lo que te dejé en el ejemplo. Simplemente haces tu llamada ajax si res.isConfirmed es true. No veo cuál es la complicación. Sólo queda de tu parte, enviar lo que necesitas para que se envíen los datos correctos