# hacer una función sweet alert. dependiendo de la respuesta continuar o detener el script

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

Hola estoy estancado en este asunto, deseo hacer un sweet alert que continúe un script si se responde aceptado y que lo detenga si es cancelado.

Esto implementado en una función.

este este mi avance pero no logro el resultado deseado.

```
function alerta(mensaje) {

            return Swal.fire({ 
                title: 'un titulo',
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonText: 'Si',
                showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
                preConfirm: (isConfirm) => {
                    return true; 
                }
            }).then(response => {
                Swal.close();
                return response
                .value; 
            });

        }
        async function getcon() {

            var a = await alerta('deseas continuar');

            return a

        }
        a = getcon();

        console.log(a);

        if (a == false) {
            console.log("retornamos");
            return;
        };
```

lo pongo en psudo código

```
función confirmación(){
     sweetalert2()
}

$(mi boton).click() {

     si (!confirmación()){
     retornar
     }

     
     mas script

}
```

que no se ejecute mas script si la promesa no sea resuelta

Comment: Quizás [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/590144/184555) te pueda ayudar

Comment: gracias por lo que me muestras pero lo que deseo que la funcion sweetalert me retorne una variable o estado que pueda condicionar para seguir el scrip o no

Comment: Bueno, no entiendo por qué al hacer uso de la propiedad isConfirmed no te puede servir o en dado caso isDismissed no te puede funcionar

Comment: gracias por tu tiempo,  no quiero hacer uso de  then isConfirmed , , sweet alert usare como una función común para crear mis mensajes de confirmación. no quiero meter mi código dentro de is confirmed  si no que me devuelva por ejemplo true asi continuar con mi código o no  dependiendo de la respuesta.  pue un psudo código en la pregunta inicial.

Comment: Creo que definitivamente no leíste [la documentación](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#handling-buttons) del propio SweetAlert o no la entendiste. Precisamente **true** es lo que te devuelve **isConfirmed** que es lo que te dejé en mi primer comentario y es lo que hace. Es difícil que no hagas uso del then porque SweetAlert te devuelve una promesa y debes resolverla para saber qué pasó al momento del usuario interactuar con SweetAlert

Comment: en todo caso, puedo crear una variable en el then y usarla mas abajo, pero como hago que no se ejecute hasta que la promesa ser resuelva.  dado que al usarla en la condicional me da error la variable no existe. dado que se esta en espera del resolve. muchas gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: Debes leer sobre scopes en JS. Si asignas una variable dentro del then te dará que no existe, así mismo si solo la declaras dentro del then. Además, el método then es precisamente para resolver las respuesta. Lee sobre promesas también

Answer (score 0):

La verdad yo para un caso así no use sweet alert, envié los datos por ajax y con jquery confirm hice la validación. Lee la documentación es bastante sencillo, igualmente te dejo una parte del codigo que usé para validar eso:

```
function submit_with_ajax(url, title, content, parameters, callback) {
    $.confirm({
        theme: 'material',
        title: title,
        icon: 'fa fa-info',
        content: content,
        columnClass: 'small',
        typeAnimated: true,
        cancelButtonClass: 'btn-primary',
        draggable: true,
        dragWindowBorder: false,
        buttons: {
            info: {
                text: "Si",
                btnClass: 'btn-primary',
                action: function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: url, //window.location.pathname
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: parameters,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false,
                    }).done(function (data) {
                        if (!data.hasOwnProperty('error')) {
                            callback(data);
                            return false;
                        }
                        //alert(data['error']);
                        message_error(data);
                    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
                    }).always(function (data) {

                    });
                }
            },
            danger: {
                text: "No",
                btnClass: 'btn-red',
                action: function () {

                }
            },
        }
    })
}
```

Con eso valida si da en la opción de Si o No.

Comment: hola Wilmer, de la forma como tu me muestras, si lo se usar. pero lo que busco es implementarla en una función para poder llamarla en en varios lugares. luego de la confirmación hacer mi ajax(o lo que tenga de código), pero seguida y fuera  de la función sweet alert

Comment: Esa función es genérica, la puedes usar en cualquier parte. Porque lo unico que hace es validar si da clic en Si o en No, ya que los datos que necesitas para lo que sigue lo envias a la función, como la url, el titulo de la alerta, el mensaje de la alerta, los parametros, etc.